# Absolute DIV Block with header and scrollable list container

Tags: html, css, sidebar, scrollable

I'm trying to create a sidebar like the one in the image. The header block with textbox has a variable size and expands when you click on the plus icon. The answers block is a scrollable list of items and goes from the bottom of the header to the bottom of the sidebar.
The sidebar block (which contains the header and answers) must be positioned absolute.

Till now I've done this with javascript and calculated on each user-action the top-distance of the absolute answers-block. This caused some problems on changing function-code and so on.

Now I want to do it with CSS-only.

I've tried it with table, table-rows and table-cells which worked well in Chrome but not in FF or IE.

Is this possible to get the described functionality with pure CSS?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tL9chL15/

```
.sidebar {
    width: 400px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.table-wrapper {
    display : table;
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
}

.content {
    display: table-cell;
    height: auto;
}

.scroll {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    display: table-row;
    background: lightyellow;
}

.container {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}

.list {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="table-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="content">
                <h2>Header</h2>
                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="scroll">
            <div class="list">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="item">
                        Item 1
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: sidebar]